# Start automaticly Function JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <div  class="scroll-btn hidden-sm hidden-xs wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="1.4s">
     <a id="introjs" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="introJs().start();">
         <span class="mouse">
         <span class="weel">
         <span></span>
         </span>
         </span>
     </a>
 </div>
```

Can i start to onclick funtion automatic on page load or on page ready.
Not on click #introjs element.

Comment: Yes you can, if you use a proper event handler, all you have to do is trigger it.

Comment: You can write a function call in window.load event to get a function executed on page load

Comment: Thats worked.  @adeneo;
            function bodyOnloadHandler() {
                introJs().start();
            }
           <body onload="bodyOnloadHandler()">

Thanks for comments friends

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Run JavaScript function when the DOM is "ready"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7992342/run-javascript-function-when-the-dom-is-ready)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use JQuery's **$(document).ready()**

or without JQuery, something like this would work in about 98% of browsers:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});
```

There's a great answer here with a bit more detail on the subject https://stackoverflow.com/a/800010/8055700

Comment: can i add time interval this function?  ex. after the 3 second started . My English not perfect sorry for this =)

Comment: Sure you can. Check out the setTimeout() and setInterval() functions. Really good tutorial here: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

Comment: You should avoid to link to w3schools, even after years they still suffer from inaccuracies and lack important informations. E.g. they write `[...]The setTimeout() and setInterval() are both methods of the HTML DOM Window object.[...]` which is not essential wrong, but they are both utility _functions_ (not _methods_) exposed by the `window` object, or nowadays are part of the window or webworker global scope.